# Searching with regex in superboxselect extjs

Tags: regex, extjs, extjs4

I need to configure superboxselect component of extjs4 and make it search with regular expression. Does anybody have any idea which function should i override or does extjs already have a function or attribute which supports this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question but ExtJS supports [Regular Expressions](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/RegExp).
You can search a string with RegExp like this:

```
var regex = /in/g; //or new RegExp("in","g");
var result = regex.exec("this is the string to search in");
console.log(result[1]);
```

From the docs:

> If the match succeeds, the exec method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has
>   the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each
>   capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was
>   captured. If the match fails, the exec method returns null.